# Non-linear first order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What technique should I use to solve the following first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation:
$$y'(x)+\log (y(x))=-x-1$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there supposed to be a closed form solution? Looks like you might be stuck with numerical methods.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the solution should be the following: $y(x)=1$

Comment: If you substitute that into the ODE, you get $y' +\log (y) = 0 + \log(1) = 0 \ne -x - 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$y'+\log y=-x-1$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-x-\log y-1$

$(x+\log y+1)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-1$

Let $u=x+\log y+1$ ,

Then $x=u-\log y-1$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{1}{y}$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{1}{y}\right)=-1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}-\dfrac{u}{y}=-1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{u}{y}-1$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{u-y}{y}$

$(u-y)\dfrac{dy}{du}=uy$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $v=u-y$ ,

Then $y=u-v$

$\dfrac{dy}{du}=1-\dfrac{dv}{du}$

$\therefore v\left(1-\dfrac{dv}{du}\right)=u(u-v)$

$v-v\dfrac{dv}{du}=u^2-uv$

$v\dfrac{dv}{du}=(u+1)v-u^2$

Let $s=u+1$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dv}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{du}=\dfrac{dv}{ds}$

$\therefore v\dfrac{dv}{ds}=sv-(s-1)^2$

$v\dfrac{dv}{ds}=sv-s^2+2s-1$

Let $t=\dfrac{s^2}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{ds}=\dfrac{dv}{dt}\dfrac{dt}{ds}=s\dfrac{dv}{dt}$

$\therefore sv\dfrac{dv}{dt}=sv-s^2+2s-1$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v-s+2-\dfrac{1}{s}$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dt}=v\pm\sqrt{2t}+2\pm\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2t}}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind in the canonical form.

Please follow the method in https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf